# Is there a faster way to create a CVPixelBuffer from a UIImage in Swift?

Tags: swift, video, uiimage, buffer, cvpixelbuffer

**Task:** Record a video in real time with a filter applied to it

**Problem** Getting a CVPixelBuffer from a modified UIImage is too slow

My camera's output is being filtered and going right to a UIImageView so that the user can see the effect in real time, even when not recording video or taking a photo. I'd like *some way* to record this changing UIImage to video, so it doesn't need to be like the way I'm doing now. Currently, I'm doing it by appending CVPixelBuffer's to an assetWriter, but since I'm applying a filter to a UIImage, I translate the UIImage back to a buffer. I've tested with and without the UIImage -> buffer, so I've proven that's causing the unacceptable slow down.

Below is the code inside captureOutput, commented to be clear what is going on, and the method for getting the UIImage buffer:

```
// this function is called to output the device's camera output in realtime
    func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection){

        if(captureOutput){

            // create ciImage from buffer
            let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)
            let cameraImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer!)

            // set UIImage to ciImage
            image = UIImage(ciImage: cameraImage)


            if let ciImage = image?.ciImage {

                // apply filter to CIImage
                image = filterCIImage(with:ciImage)

                // make CGImage and apply orientation
                image = UIImage(cgImage: (image?.cgImage)!, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.right)

                // get format description, dimensions and current sample time
                let formatDescription = CMSampleBufferGetFormatDescription(sampleBuffer)!
                self.currentVideoDimensions = CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetDimensions(formatDescription)
                self.currentSampleTime = CMSampleBufferGetOutputPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer)

                // check if user toggled video recording 
                // and asset writer is ready
                if(videoIsRecording && self.assetWriterPixelBufferInput?.assetWriterInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData == true){
                    // get pixel buffer from UIImage - SLOW!
                    let filteredBuffer = buffer(from: image!)

                    // append the buffer to the asset writer
                    let success = self.assetWriterPixelBufferInput?.append(filteredBuffer!, withPresentationTime: self.currentSampleTime!)

                    if success == false {
                        print("Pixel Buffer failed")
                    }

                }

            }


            DispatchQueue.main.async(){
                // update UIImageView with filtered camera output
                imageView!.image = image
            }

        }

    }


    // UIImage to buffer method:
    func buffer(from image: UIImage) -> CVPixelBuffer? {
        let attrs = [kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey: kCFBooleanTrue, kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey: kCFBooleanTrue] as CFDictionary
        var pixelBuffer : CVPixelBuffer?
        let status = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, Int(image.size.width), Int(image.size.height), kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB, attrs, &pixelBuffer)
        guard (status == kCVReturnSuccess) else {
            return nil
        }

        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer!, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))
        let pixelData = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer!)

        let rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
        let context = CGContext(data: pixelData, width: Int(image.size.width), height: Int(image.size.height), bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(pixelBuffer!), space: rgbColorSpace, bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.noneSkipFirst.rawValue)

        context?.translateBy(x: 0, y: image.size.height)
        context?.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)

        UIGraphicsPushContext(context!)
        image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height))
        UIGraphicsPopContext()
        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer!, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))

        return pixelBuffer
    }
```

Comment: Not related to your issue but using optional biding to force unwrap it later doesn't make any sense `(image?.cgImage)!`. `if let ciImage = image?.ciImage, let filteredImage = filterCIImage(with: ciImage) {`

Comment: Andrea - I can display the filtered output just fine, but I would like to record that filtered output as video so that I can save it. I can achieve that by getting the camera's output buffer, turning that into a UIImage, filtering that UIImage and updating the UIImageView, and then getting that filtered image and turning it into a buffer and appending that buffer to a asset writer. Problem is that it's slow to translate the filtered image to a buffer while all the rest is going on.

Comment: Alternatively, I wish there was some way of recording that UIImageView in real time or getting the buffer from the UIImage from a property and have it be fast enough where it wouldn't make much of a performance impact.